# Updating php mongo on Yum

Tags: php, mongodb, yum

I'm trying to update from **PHP 5.6** to **PHP 7** on my Vagrant machine. I'm more or less following this guide https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/12/04/Install-PHP-7.2-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora

I've done the following:

> wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
>   wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
>   rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

I follow the regular steps for activating the packages, but then when I try to update through

> **yum update**

I get the following error:

```
php-pecl-mongo-1.6.16-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (@remi-php56)  
Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64   
Removing: php-common-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
```

The error is actually longer. But in short, it indicates that the I need the Mongo Driver for PHP 7.

How can I update this though? I'm at loss!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The [mongo](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) extension is only for PHP 5.
- The [mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) extension is for PHP 5.5+ and PHP 7+

So yum blocks the transaction (expected) as one of the installed extension is not compatible with PHP 7.

You have to remove this extension before the upgrade.

Be aware than **mongodb** and **mongo** are really different extensions, with very different API.

Usually people use the [mongodb/mongodb](https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb) library to have a high level API

You can also consider using [alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter](https://packagist.org/packages/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter) library which provides the old **mongo** API using **mongodb** extension.

Comment: Thanks alot this is really helpful